# Create XML node with empty text content and with a named closing tag using ElementTree.SubElement

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I can't seem to find a way to generate a sub-element like this

```
<child attr="something"></child>
```

Using the following code:

`myChild = ElementTree.SubElement(root, tag="child", attrib={'attr': 'something'})`

I always get:

```
<child attr="something" />
```

Unless I at least add:

```
whiteSpace = " "
myChild.text = whiteSpace
```

This is very annoying.

Is there a way that I can generate null text for the element with ElementTree?

**UPDATES:**

After some tries, I tend to agree that it really shouldn't matter. The reason why I asked is  that I wanted to generate Xcode workspace file which uses empty content for it's project nodes. But I found that the default subElement actually works as well. So I won't put any more efforts in making the output XML in the "identical" format as the normal Xcode workspace.

Case closed.

Comment: why is it annoying? Its normal valid xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is probably: There is no way to achieve what I wanted in the beginning.

But as the updates in my question said. The difference between the two mentioned formats really doesn't matter. They both work as valid XML.